How to show $\varphi_t^*(\mathcal L_XT)= \mathcal L_{(\varphi_t^{-1})_*X}~ (\varphi_t^* T)$?
$X$ is a vector field. $\varphi_t$ is its flow, namely
$$
\partial_t \varphi_t(p) = X(\varphi_t(p))  \tag{1}
$$
I want to show
$$
\varphi_t^*(\mathcal L_XT)= \mathcal L_{(\varphi_t^{-1})_*X}~ (\varphi_t^* T)
\tag{2}
$$
where $T$ is covariant tensor.  $\varphi_t^*$ is pullback induced by $\varphi_t$. And $(\varphi_t^{-1})_*$ is the tangent mapping induced by $\varphi_t^{-1}$, namely the differential of $\varphi_t^{-1}$.
I'm not very familiar with the lie derivative. Generally, I treat
$$
\mathcal L_{X} T (p)
=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\varphi_t^* (T_{\varphi_t(p)})-T_p}{t}
=
\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \varphi_t^* (T_{\varphi_t(p)})
\tag{3}
$$
The problem is origin from the red line of picture below. I want to show the red line equal to zero. I made some simplification. But I was afraid I  missed something, so the picture is added.
What I try:  I tried a few things, but it wasn't  rigorous. First, I think
$$
\varphi_t^{-1}= \varphi_{-t}  \tag{4}
$$
Assume the flow of $(\varphi_{-t})_* X$ is $\varphi_s$, then I feel
$$
\partial_s \varphi_s(p) =[(\varphi_{-t})_* X] (\varphi_s(p))
=X(\varphi_{t+s}(p))
\tag{5}
$$
Therefore, the flow of $(\varphi_{-t})_* X$ is $\varphi_{t+s}$,  where $s$ is variate. Next, from (3), there is
$$
\begin{align}
\left[\mathcal L_{(\varphi_t^{-1})_*X}~ (\varphi_t^* T)\right] (p)
&=
\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}
\frac{
\varphi_{t+s}^*(\varphi_t^* T)_{\varphi_{t+s}(p)}
-
\varphi_t^*(\varphi_t^* T)_{\varphi_t(p)}
}{s}
\tag{6}\\
&=
\varphi_t^* 
\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}
\frac{
\varphi_{s}^*(\varphi_t^* T)_{\varphi_{t+s}(p)}
-
(\varphi_t^* T)_{\varphi_t (p)}
}{s}
\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Then, I don't know how to deal the limit. And I feel  it is not $\mathcal L_XT$.
Besides, I wrote some of these steps by feeling. So, there must be some wrong. But to show what I think, I wrote it down. Thanks for any help.




Proposition 12.36 in Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds may be relevant

@Chris  Thanks your help. Proposition 12.36 is useful to deal my problem.

After Chris' hint, I found a way around the red line. Namely, to prove
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Big|_{s=0} (\varphi_{t+s}^* g(t))=-\varphi_t^* (\mathcal L_{X(t)} g(t))
\tag{1}
$$
For convenience, I denote $g(t)$ as $g$,  $X(t)$ as $X$. There is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Big|_{s=0} (\varphi_{t+s}^* g(t))(p) 
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Big|_{s=0}
[\varphi_{t+s}^* (g_{\varphi_{t+s}(p)})]
\tag{2}\\
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Big|_{s=0}
[\varphi_t^* \varphi_s^* (g_{\varphi_{s}(\varphi_{t}(p))})    ]
\tag{3}\\
&=
\varphi_t^*  
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\Big|_{s=0}
 \varphi_s^* (g_{\varphi_{s}(\varphi_{t}(p))})    
\tag{4}\\
&= - \varphi_t^* [(\mathcal L_X g)(\varphi_t(p))]
\tag{5}\\
&=
-[\varphi_t^*(\mathcal L_X g)](p)
\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Notice, the minus sign of (5) is because $\partial_t \varphi_t = -X$  in the picture of problem.  And the above process is the proof of Proposition 12.36 mentioned by Chris.
